# Doctrine2: calling flush multiple times

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a question concerning **Doctrine** and entities on **Symfony** 2.3.

According to the v2.3 *"Documentation Book"* chapter *"Databases and Doctrine"* > [Saving Related Entities](https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities), the example create simultaneously a new row in both `product` and `category` tables and associates  `product.category_id`  value with the `id` of the new **category** item.

The problem is that the controller action creates a new **Product** and a new **Category** anytime it is invoked!

In order to just create a new **product** and associate its `category_id` with an existing **category** `id`, this is the **routing.yml** route:

```yaml
acme_store_create_product_by_category:
path:     /create/newproduct/{name}/{categoryId}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Default:createProduct }
```

> I made a test passing parameters via URL:
> /web/store/create/newproduct/Kayak/12

I did something like this which seems working fine:

```php
public function createProductAction($name, $categoryId)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ( $em->getRepository("AcmeStoreBundle:Category")->findOneById($categoryId) ) {

        $product = new Product();

        $product->setName($name);
        $product->setPrice(220);
        $product->setDescription("This is just a test");

        $em->persist($product);

        $em->flush();

        $newproduct = $em->getRepository("AcmeStoreBundle:Product")->find($product->getId());
        /** Create new product and populate $newproduct with its data */


        $repository = $em->getRepository("AcmeStoreBundle:Category")->find($categoryId);

        $newproduct->setCategory($repository);

        $em->persist($newproduct);

        $em->flush();
        /** Update the id_category field of the new product with parameter $categoryId */

        //exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($product));

        return new Response('Create product ' . $name . ' with category id ' . $categoryId);

    } else {

        return new Response('It doesn\'t exists any category with id ' . $categoryId);
    }
}
```

My doubt in this case is: Is it a good practice to invoke `flush()` method two times in the same **action** ? In this case I would like to create a new **product** selecting the related **category** from a "list box".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it mostly depends on your application domain. If you run `flush` two times it means you're running two transactions. In the first one you're persisting a product, in the second one a category. So if the first transaction fails (let's say you have a unique key on the product name and you're trying to persist a product with the same name so you get a duplicate key exception) then ask yourself if it's OK to go on and persist a category. I don't think we can answer that easily here because I think it depends on your application logic, what that endpoint is supposed to do, what happens if you end up having a product and not a category or vice-versa.

You should also consider that if you get an exception during the first transaction your code won't handle that error and the second transaction will therefore fail. When an exception like a duplicate key occurs all entities are detached and the entity manager doesn't know anymore how to manage things. So you'll have to reset it or you're going to get an `EntityManager is closed` issue.

```php
try {
    // first transaction
    $entityManager->persist($entityOne);
    $entityManager->flush();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    /* ... handle the exception */ 
    $entityManager->resetManager();
}

// now we can safely run a second transaction here
```

I hope this answers your question :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Francesco :-) ! 
I'm currently under big effort in order to switch on Entities-like approach and ORM. It's pretty far from PDO or mysqli libraries methods. 
Yes, the example I posted was just a curiosity of mine strictly connected with the example in the Symfony Documentation Book, not a real application of course :-) 
Anyway it's very useful your tip! 
I'm gonna implement it in my test code in order to keep in mind for future cases

Comment: Glad it helped @FabrizioSabato :-) Are you seeking any other information? I'm asking because I'm not sure this fully answers your question. It's probably best changing the question title so that this can be useful for users coming from search engines as well. Something like "Doctrine2: calling flush multiple times"?

Comment: Well, now i am reading some documentation about webforms and beahviours related to them. I am pretty sure that this will bring out some more informations that I'll be really happy to share within this discussion. 
Ok, according to your advice I'll change the title.

Comment: If this answers your question you should flag it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the edited code snippet.

```
    public function createProductAction($name, $categoryId)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    
        if ( $em->getRepository("AcmeStoreBundle:Category")->findOneById($categoryId) ) {
    
            $repository = $em->getRepository("AcmeStoreBundle:Category")->find($categoryId);
    
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setName($name);
            $product->setPrice(220);
            $product->setDescription("This is just a test");
            $product->setCategory($repository);
    
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();
    
            return new Response('Create product ' . $name . ' with category id ' . $categoryId);
    
        } else {
    
            return new Response('It doesn\'t exists any category with id ' . $categoryId);
        }
    }
```